# python file-like buffer object

Tags: python, io, buffer

I've written a buffer class that provides a File-like interface with `read`, `write`, `seek`, `tell`, `flush` methods to a simple string in memory. Of course it is incomplete (e.g. I didn't write `readline`). It's purpose is to be filled by a background thread from some external data source, but let a user treat it like a file. I'd expect it to contain a relatively small amount of data (maybe 50K max)

Is there a better way to do this instead of writing it from scratch?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the standard Python modules [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) or [`cStringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) to obtain an in-memory buffer which implements the [file interface](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects).

`cStringIO` is implemented in C, and will be faster, so you should use that version if possible.

If you're using Python 3 you should use the [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) instead of `StringIO` and [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instead of `cStringIO`.

Comment: I think that's what I'm looking for. But are these classes thread-safe? I will have separate reader and writer threads.

Comment: Pythons GIL means that thread safety is highly unlikely to be a problem, as two threads don't execute at the same time.

Comment: That doesn't make it thread-safe. If it did, then we wouldn't need thread safety on single-core processors.

Comment: Thanks to @Sean1708 for [including](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13810461) the Python3 notes:)

Answer (score 7):

I think you might be looking for `StringIO`.